# all intellibot plugins are not working/downloading for PyCharm RobotFramework

Tags: plugins, pycharm, robotframework, selenium2library, intellibot

I am trying to setup Robot-framework and I'd like to use selenium2library as a library. And while downloading intellibot@patched / intellibot @seleniumlibrary etc. from marketplace of pycharm and click to restart IDE, it raises the following error;

[image]

So, I cannot download the selenium2library as plugins. I tried to download .jar file as offline. But the same issue occurred.

Is there any different way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning Wi-Fi off while installing intellij.jar offline worked for me and fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Intellibot plugin available in the pycharm IDE is not maintained so does not work properly sometimes, instead you can use .jar file form here https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot/blob/master/intellibot.jar and add manually in the pycharm IDE.